# Assigning value to radio

Tags: javascript

I been given a task of doing simple maths with using JS, I have this:

```js
function multiply() {
  var type = parseFloat(document.form1.type.value);
  var quantity = parseFloat(document.form1.quantity.value);
  var ans = type * quantity;
  document.form1.answer.value = ans;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <div class="type">
    Ticket type
    <input id="low" name="type" type="radio" value=1 checked>
    <label for="low">Low</label>
    <input id="mid" name="type" type="radio" value=2>
    <label for="mid">Mid</label>
    <input id="high" name="type" type="radio" value=3>
    <label for="high">high</label>
  </div>
  <br> quantity
  <input type=text name="quantity" value=1>
  <br> Cost
  <input type="button" onclick="multiply();">
  <input type="text" name="answer" readonly>
</form>
```

The idea is to select "type" from radio "buttons" (or whatever it counts as), enter the quantity and do simple maths of multiplying one by another to get total "cost".

Problem is that it doesn't appear to be able to read off the value from checked radio which gives me an error.

Edit: some people figure to make my question and code snippet neater. Ty for that. It appears it was just me being an idiot and forgetting to add a name to quantity input and (it seems) missreading the error.

Comment: You missed name for `quantity` input

Comment: Cheers, guess that would been the next problem if i got the original one fixed xD

Comment: Now you named the button with `quantity`: still wrong. And it is not the next problem, but the first problem. ;-)

Comment: The text input needs the quantity name, not the button

Comment: *facepalm* I'm an idiot ¬_¬

Comment: So now what is your question?

Comment: aaaaaand it works... sorry its just me being an idiot it appears...

Comment: @trincot Well, if ya dont mind too much, is it possible to achieve the same effect without the need of a button?

Comment: You already accepted an answer, so I suppose you're OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value **type** in your script code is not correct, you should change it for **ticketType**

```
function multiply(){
   var ticketType = parseFloat(document.form1.type.value);
   var quantity = parseFloat(document.form1.quantity.value);
   var ans = ticketType * quantity;
   document.form1.answer.value = ans;
}
```

Add **name** attribute to quantity tag

```
<input type=text name="quantity" value=1>
```

Comment: Why would the OP need to change `type` to `ticketType`?

Comment: Well all i had to do is to add name to quantity input. Variable names slightly differed cause i forgot to change them all which i edited in OP once i saw it.